# What all detail will get from youtube api by just passing forUsername param

Tags: api, google-api, youtube-api

I need to fetch all possible user details of a user by just providing a username from youtube API. I need to know the response

```
forUsername
```

Answer (score 1):

**Answer**: There is no API that will allow you type a username from YouTube and get the users details back.

## Possible alternative

However if you have the user in question logged in though Oauth2 you can use one of the following options.

## userinfo endpoint

If you have a user login using Oauth2 then you can request profile scope and this will allow you to use the userinfo endpoint to request information about this user.  This is part of the open id connect [standard claim response](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#StandardClaims)

## people.get me

You can also use the Google peole api to get information back about the currently authenticated user [people.get](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get?apix_params=%7B%22userId%22%3A%22me%22%7D)

```
{
 "kind": "plus#person",
 "etag": "\"4DZKD8nJom0F9AKh7PGs_B0kK-A/9QJ_cErg4m2KU4Yr_BYLRInY36g\"",
 "emails": [
  {
   "value": "xxxxx@gmail.com",
   "type": "account"
  }
 ],
 "id": "117200475572775346",
 "displayName": "Linda Lawton",
 "name": {
  "familyName": "Lawton",
  "givenName": "Linda"
 },
 "image": {
  "url": "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-a1CWlFnA5xE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAl1I/UcwPajZOuN4/s50/photo.jpg",
  "isDefault": false
 },
 "language": "en"
}
```